# Java: detecting object name?

Tags: java, class

I am working on a little tiny game, where there is a Attacker and a Defender.

```
Player Attacker = new Player();
Player Defender = new Player();
        
class Player {
    int armees = 0;
    int tarningar = 0;
    Dice Dices[];

    Player() {
        armees = 10;
        // if object name is Attacker, tarninger = 3, if defender = 2
        Dices= new Dice[tarningar];

        for(int i = 0; i < Dices.length; i++) {
            Dices[i]=new Dice();
        }
    }
}
```

I have commented inside the code above, where i wish to have a if statement to determine how many dices it should have.

If this is not possible to do, another way of doing this maybe?

I also tried to

```
Attacker.tarningar = 3;
Defender.tarningar = 2;
```

right under where the object gets defined in main, but it doesn't work, because it has already ran `Player()` inside class.

(I'm still new to java) Thanks

Comment: You should use lowercase characters to begin all variable names, in this case `attacker` and `defender` and also `dices`.  This makes it easy to tell them apart from class names like `Player` and `Dice`.  It is also standard Java convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could do:

```
Player(boolean isAttacker){
    armees = 10;
    // if object name is Attacker, tarninger = 3, if defender = 2
    int diceNum;
    if (isAttacker) diceNum = 2;
    else diceNum = 3;
    Dices= new Dice[diceNum];
    for(int i=0;i<Dices.length;i++){
        Dices[i]=new Dice();
    }
}
```

Then you will need to tell the player if it is attacking or defending when it is constructed.

```
Player p = new Player(true); // creates an attacker
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to this:

```
Player Attacker = new Player(true);
Player Defender = new Player(false);


class Player {
    boolean attacker;
    int armees = 0;
    int tarningar = 0;
    Dice Dices[];

    Player(boolean attacker) {
        this.attacker = attacker;
        armees = 10;
        tarninger = attacker ? 3 : 2;
        Dices= new Dice[tarningar];

        for(int i = 0; i < Dices.length; i++) {
            Dices[i] = new Dice();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Erick that was the idea, but the initial code was so poorly formatted so I decided to left it as it is, thinking that author could easily find out what I meant, or maybe even read some manuals on java programming.

Comment: Finished the code by adding the attacker paramater, removed -1, +1.

Answer (score 2):

You should add a variable determining whether this is an attacker or a defender. Or even better, if they do different things, create subclasses for attacker and defender.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to differentiate based on variable names, it's not possible because that information is removed during compiler optimizations. If the instances are accessible, you could do

```
if (this == attacker)
{
    ...
}
```

or you could introduce a new field to store name

```
Player attacker = new Player("Attacker");
```

or perhaps an enum.

```
Player attacker = new Player(PlayerType.Attacker);
```